# Specify 'alternate characters' in base64 decoding/encoding in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, base64

I am trying to port some code from python to node. The code is as follows:

```
//returns the UID contained in the var uid decoded to an int:
uid = 'ABCDE'
struct.unpack(">I", base64.b64decode(uid + 'A==', "[]"))[0] / 4

//encodes the UID int in uidint into the B64 UID:
uidint = 270532
base64.b64encode(struct.pack(">I", uidint * 4), "[]")[0:5]
```

I have already found a library that replaces the pack/unpacking functionality provided by python's struct class.

However, python's [implementation](http://base64encode.net/python-base64-b64encode) of base64 has support for allowing alternate characters. Unfortunately, node's does not.

Here is my work-in-progress port:

```
uid = 'ABCDE';
decoded = new Buffer(uid+'A==', 'base64').toString('ascii');
console.log(decoded);
test = jspack.Unpack(">I",decoded)[0] / 4;
console.log(test);
```

Currently the first console.log returns weird characters. the second returns NaN. Which makes sense why it'd do that.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to replicate python's implementation of this pattern. I've been scanning through libraries on npm and didn't find anything that might suggest this as a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace them manually before creating buffer:

```
new Buffer(
  (uid+'A==')
    .replace(/\+/g, '[')
    .replace(/\//g, ']')
, 'base64').toString('ascii')
```

Comment: Wow, that never occurred me. I guess that's one of those "so obvious you don't think of it", however, it's still spitting out the same NaN when it's unpacked. So maybe the problem is with jspack.Unpack. I'm actually not quite sure how it works in python or what's it's used to accomplished, I'm just trying to port it for an IRCd project I'm working on (P10 userid numerics). I'm at a loss at point. I guess if it's a problem with jspack, it's not relevant to this base64 question.